# Why quoted word is not hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

In the following example, a word in quotes is not hyphenated, instead it is if unquoted. Also a `\hyphenation{}` statement has no effect.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\hyphenation{im-ma-tu-ri-tà}

\begin{document}

This doesn't hyphenate the word `immaturità':

Ciò che si chiama forse immaginazione infantile è il prodotto
dell'``immaturità'' della mente, in rapporto con la povertà in cui
lasciamo il bambino e l'ignoranza in cui egli si trova, occorre prima
arricchire la sua vita.

This instead hyphenates the same word:

Ciò che si chiama forse immaginazione infantile è il prodotto
dell'immaturità della mente, in rapporto con la povertà in cui lasciamo il
bambino e l'ignoranza in cui egli si trova, occorre prima arricchire la
sua vita.

\end{document}
```

What I have to do to force hyphenation? The text is in a blockquote, so I cannot change the word order or the line length.

Comment: Use `dell'\hspace{0pt}``immaturità''`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a space between `dell'` and ``, this confuses LaTeX.

Comment: I found that writing dell'\! ``immaturità'' is even better. The resulting space before the opening quote is roughly equivalent to \, that I was adding in the real document to separate the single and double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid a normal space after the apostrophe, preferring a small kerning, but in this case some rules conflict with each other.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,italian]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

This doesn't hyphenate the word `immaturità':

Ciò che si chiama forse immaginazione infantile è il prodotto
dell'\,``\nobreak\hspace{0pt}immaturità'' della mente, in rapporto con la povertà in cui
lasciamo il bambino e l'ignoranza in cui egli si trova, occorre prima
arricchire la sua vita.

This instead hyphenates the same word:

Ciò che si chiama forse immaginazione infantile è il prodotto
dell'immaturità della mente, in rapporto con la povertà in cui lasciamo il
bambino e l'ignoranza in cui egli si trova, occorre prima arricchire la
sua vita.

\parbox[t]{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
dell'\,``\nobreak\hspace{0pt}immaturità''
}

\end{document}
```

The last piece shows all hyphenation points, no need of a `\hyphenation` command.

The solution is admittedly ugly, but you can improve it by defining

```
\newcommand{\?}{\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

and typing

```
dell'\,``\?immaturità''
```

should the need arise.

[image]